# How to NFS share 'RO' for all user and 'RW' to some ip's

Tags: linux, permissions, nfs, readonly

I'm trying to figure out how can I NFS share same directory RO for all users and RW for some IPs.

> OS: Arch Linux & File System: ZFS

I have a config in "/etc/exports.d/testPool.aaa.exports"

```
/testPool/aaa 192.168.10.16(rw,wdelay,hide,nocrossmnt,secure,no_subtree_check,secure_locks,acl,no_pnfs,mountpoint,sync,root_squash,all_squash,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534,sec=sys)

/testPool/aaa *(ro,wdelay,hide,nocrossmnt,secure,no_subtree_check,secure_locks,acl,no_pnfs,mountpoint,sync,root_squash,all_squash,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534,sec=sys)
```

With this conf I can't write even when I am using that IP.
If I use IP's instead " * " for RW and RO everything works.
But when I use " * " to "RO" other lines are ignored and everybody becomes readonly.

**Can you tell me why I can't use " * " and IP together?**

---

Do I need 777 permissions to write as nobody? 
Or do I need to map nobody user to local user for security reasons?

Comment: Is this NFS v3 or v4?

Comment: v4-v3 doesn't matter. it must all about nfs export conf.

Comment: Suit yourself. Configuration works perfectly for me here. I wanted to check our differences.